# Persisting datatables in viewstate and databinding

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-2.0

I am passing in a start date, an end date, a SQL stored procedure, and a identifying area code into a shared function to populate five declared datatables.

```
    Public Shared Function getNBOCAPData(ByVal startDate As DateTime, ByVal endDate As DateTime, ByVal sp As String, ByVal orgCode As String) As DataTable
        Dim SqlConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CancerRegisterConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString)
        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
        getNBOCAPData = New DataTable
        Try
            SqlConn.Open()
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sqlCmd.Connection = SqlConn
            sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 300
            sqlCmd.CommandText = sp

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startDate)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", endDate)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserOrgCode", orgCode)
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

            getNBOCAPData.Load(reader)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Common.LogError(ex, True)
        Finally
            SqlConn.Close()
            SqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function
```

The results of this function are then passed into the datatables like this

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim patiDataTable As DataTable = getNBOCAPData(Request.QueryString("startDate"), Request.QueryString("endDate"), "NBOCAP_DOWNLOAD_PATI", Request.QueryString("orgCode"))
        Dim tumDataTable As DataTable = getNBOCAPData(Request.QueryString("startDate"), Request.QueryString("endDate"), "NBOCAP_DOWNLOAD_TUM", Request.QueryString("orgCode"))
        Dim surDataTable As DataTable = getNBOCAPData(Request.QueryString("startDate"), Request.QueryString("endDate"), "NBOCAP_DOWNLOAD_SUR", Request.QueryString("orgCode"))
        Dim cheDataTable As DataTable = getNBOCAPData(Request.QueryString("startDate"), Request.QueryString("endDate"), "NBOCAP_DOWNLOAD_CHE", Request.QueryString("orgCode"))
        Dim patDataTable As DataTable = getNBOCAPData(Request.QueryString("startDate"), Request.QueryString("endDate"), "NBOCAP_DOWNLOAD_PATH", Request.QueryString("orgCode"))

        Dim hidCount As Integer = 0

        If patiDataTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            divPati.Visible = False
            hidCount += 1
        End If

        If tumDataTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            divTum.Visible = False
            hidCount += 1
        End If

        If surDataTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            divSur.Visible = False
            hidCount += 1
        End If

        If cheDataTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            divChe.Visible = False
            hidCount += 1
        End If

        If pathDataTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            divPath.Visible = False
            hidCount += 1
        End If

        If hidCount = 5 Then
            divNoResults.Visible = True
            divInstructions.Visible = False
        Else
            ViewState("patiDataTable") = patiDataTable
            ViewState("tumDataTable") = tumDataTable
            ViewState("surDataTable") = surDataTable
            ViewState("cheDataTable") = cheDataTable
            ViewState("pathDataTable") = pathDataTable
        End If
End Sub
```

The databinding is done like this

```
    Public Shared Sub RetRptBySPNBOCAP(ByRef dg As GridView, ByVal dataTable As DataTable)
        dg.DataSource = dataTable
        dg.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Then in preparation for the datatables to be sent to an Excel file the data in ViewState is set to a DataTable like this, but the dataTable.Rows.Count() is throwing a NullReferenceException error as though the databind isn't taking place?

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim cellDate As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
    Dim dataTable As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim prefix As String = "Pati_NBOCAP"

    Select Case (Request.QueryString("type").ToString)
        Case "Pati"
            dataTable = ViewState("patiDataTable")
        Case "Tum"
            dataTable = ViewState("tumDataTable")
            prefix = "Tum_NBOCAP"
        Case "Che"
            dataTable = ViewState("cheDataTable")
            prefix = "Che_NBOCAP"
        Case "Path"
            dataTable = ViewState("pathDataTable")
            prefix = "Path_NBOCAP"
        Case "Sur"
            dataTable = ViewState("surDataTable")
            prefix = "Sur_NBOCAP"
    End Select

    RetRptBySPNBOCAP(Results, dataTable)

    Dim rCount As Integer
    If dataTable.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        rCount = dataTable.Rows.Count()
    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, you have 2 `Page_Load` methods - are these 2 different `Pages`? Which [**`Page VIEWSTATE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx) has the data?

Comment: EdSF Thank you, but I have now solved this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know that viewstate is a per page concept. So if you put data in the viewstate of a particular page you can't retrieve them from another page. Instead of viewstate you can use Session which is the same for all the pages executed within a user session.

```
Session("patiDataTable") = patiDataTable
```

Also, viewstate is by default stored client side ans thus is not suitable for large data objects such as datatables.

Comment: DadyFuji Thank you, yes, I understand what you mean, I have now used Session variables to store the datatables and it is working as it should. I also had to change the second page load sub to cast the data to the datatable dim like this dataTable = CType(Session("patiDataTable"), System.Data.DataTable)